# Find the complex limit of a division of polynomials

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to find the following limit

$$\lim_{z \to i} \frac{z^2+1}{z^6+1}$$

It is a case $\frac{0}{0}$, note that if $z^2+1=0$ we have that $z= \pm i$ and $z^2+1=(z-i)(z+i)$, now, for the denominator term we can take $u=z^3$ and write

$$z^6+1=u^2+1=(u-i)(u+i)=(z^3-i)(z^3+i)$$

Of course, trying to factor more is a bit complicated for me, any suggestions on how to deal with the limit, clearly my idea is not to use L'Hopital.

Comment: Thanks, @MartinR.  I spent some time on appraoch0 trying to find something similar (as this seems like a common kind of problem to give students), but was unsuccessful.

Comment: @MartinR I swear to g-d, that is exactly the same search I ran!  Maybe my eyes just glazed over it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of difference of squares, use the sum of cubes formula on the denominator

$$\frac{z^2+1}{z^6+1} = \frac{z^2+1}{(z^2+1)(z^4-z^2+1)} = \frac{1}{z^4-z^2+1}$$

$$\longrightarrow \frac{1}{3}$$

Note that you get the same result with L'Hopital

$$\lim_{z\to i}\frac{z^2+1}{z^6+1} = \lim_{z\to i}\frac{2z}{6z^5} = \frac{1}{3}$$

because L'Hopital always* works with complex numbers on limits of the form $\frac{0}{0}$. This is because in that case, L'Hopital will always be equivalent to computing the limit definition of the derivative so long as the numerator and denominator are holomorphic (complex analytic) functions.